# Insert uniques couple of datas in sqlite bdd

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data like this :

```
sensor_name   timestamp
-----------   ---------
TNL09         1309539894
TNL09         1309539994
TNL27         1309540994
PWD           1309540994
```

I want to avoid duplicate values. I tried to convert the timestamp value in primaryid value to use INSERT OR REPLACE. It's work but if I have the same timestamp with a different `sensor_name` I can't insert the new data.

How I can do (if is it possible) to insert a couple of unique datas without checking by a `SELECT` request?

Comment: So even if the timestamp is for a different `sensor_name` you would still consider it to be a duplicate?

Comment: @Adam I consider duplicate if I have the same `sensor_name` with the same timestamp. `Ex TNL27 : 1309540994 TNL27 : 1309540994` . I can have to add a data like `TNL27 1309540994 and TNL09 1309540994` . Same timestamp but different sensor_name

Comment: something like `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (sensor_name,timestamp) VALUES ("TNL27",1309540994) WHERE sensor_name=TNL27 OR WHERE sensor_name=1309540994`

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table (sensor_name,timestamp) VALUES ("TNL27",1309540994) WHERE sensor_name=TNL27 OR WHERE sensor_name=1309540994
```